# ControlTemplate with "Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True" and "Control.IsMouseOver" Value="False">

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In my WPF control, I have below code. If I don't have a trigger with false, I can see the my storyboard, but if I have both ture and false triggers, I don't see any thing.

How to fix this? Appreciate your help!

```
<Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
 <StoryBoard>          
      Image with Opacity 1
 </StoryBoard>
</Trigger>        
<Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
 <StoryBoard> 
      Image with Opacity 0
 </StoryBoard>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False trigger is unnecessary. Use default control state to represent situation when Control.IsMouseOver is False. WPF automatically reverts changes made by trigger when its condition is false.

Comment: Levanovd, I tried with Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True". But it doesn't revert the storyboard. Can you please tell me which default state should I use?

Comment: Are you shure that you need Storyboard? Maybe Setter is enough to set opacity to image?